# I need to make a dictionary from a list of lists

Tags: python

I have this:

```
A = [[0, 3, 6, 11], [0, 5, 7, 11], [0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11]]
```

I want to make a diccionary from  `A` like this:

```
dic_A = { 0: [0, 3, 6, 11], 1: [0, 5, 7, 11], 2: [0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11]}
```

I have tried different ways and I can only use a for in range to solve the problem I think this can be reduced to a line somehow but I can't find the way

I tried this:

```
    dic_A = {}
    for i in range(3):
         dic_A[i] = A[i]
```

Comment: `{i:j for i,j in enumerate(A)}`

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You can, with your current code, do this: A[2][1].

Comment: I'm really sorry, it was not my intention, I change the question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [dictionary comprehension](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension) with `enumerate` to easily create the structure you desire. In my example the `i` (integer) will be the index of the child `list` and the `d` (data) will be the actual child `list`. However, there really doesn't seem much reason to do this, because the only syntactical difference will be from `A[0]` to `B.0`. You will actually have to jump through some hoops to target keys in `B` without possible errors, if you decide to use it in a ranged loop. The syntax to use it in a loop would become identical to `A`, as you would have to key `B` (ex: `B[i]`). You will also lose simple checks, like: `len(A)` to determine if the index is even available or to create a `range` based on what is known to be available. In short: You are potentially creating future problems for yourself by doing this. Whatever you are trying to accomplish with this, there is probably a much better way. If we are going to implement Occam's Razor, the "much better way" is more-than-likely to simply use the `list`.

```
A = [[0, 3, 6, 11], [0, 5, 7, 11], [0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11]]
B = {i:d for i, d in enumerate(A)}

print(B) #{0: [0, 3, 6, 11], 1: [0, 5, 7, 11], 2: [0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11]}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
dic_A = {index: array for index, array in enumerate(A)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [[0, 3, 6, 11], [0, 5, 7, 11], [0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11]]

# Create a dictionary
dic = {}

# loop through A and assign Key, value pairs based on list index
for index, value in enumerate(A):
    dic[index] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can it with a comprehension like this:

```
A = [[0, 3, 6, 11], [0, 5, 7, 11], [0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11]]
{x: y for x, y in enumerate(A)}
```

**Output:**

```
{0: [0, 3, 6, 11], 1: [0, 5, 7, 11], 2: [0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate()` inbuilt function

```
A = [[0, 3, 6, 11], [0, 5, 7, 11], [0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11]]

d = dict()
for i,el in enumerate(A):
    d[i] = el

print(d)
```